# Format and encrypt compromised USB stick with TrueCrypt to make it clean again?

Tags: usb, security, truecrypt, trojan, rootkit

Let's say I bought an used USB stick from a very professional hacker who has compromised the stick with really professional methods, the NSA or FBI would use to compromise it: Would it be safe to encrypt the entire drive with TrueCrypt 7.1a and let format it or is there still a chance that the device is still compromised?

Comment: Your text has a different order of events than your title. Please [edit]

Comment: I changed the title. I am not sure, if it's better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option (if i understand well what you are trying) is to use a Linux to write zeroes all over the USB, then use gdisk or fdisk to create a new MBR or GPT empty table, after that treat it as a non compromissed USB, create partitions, format them... and if you wish encrypt it.

Paranoid point of view: That is you have any USB (for example you found it on the street, on a mountain, etc) that can have software/data on it you do not trust/want and maybe you can think having such data can make you go in jail.

Really paranoid: Just one overwrite is not enough, really forensic experts can recover (at least, last time i checked) more than the last 83 states, so you need at least (to be safe) to overwrite it about a hundred times (better if done with special patterns); this applies to magnetic HDDs as well as for USB sticks, memory cards, SSDs, etc. This is called 'secure wipe multi pass'.

On the other side: If you have data you want to keep safe but only for your eyes, then it is much more complex, but as easy as 1,2,3... just ensure you have another medium where you can 'copy' the data, then do the 'secure wipe multi pass', after that, create the new MBR/GPT table and partitions, encrypt them, fill them with a huge file or more (in case FAT32 and >4GiB, etc) with data from random.org data (real random and not reproductible data), delete that huge file/s, copy back the data to it, then do the 'secure wipe multi pass' on the other one.

Paranoid point of view: To have data not be seen by others you need a System with full encryption, never trust anyone that say 100% system encription is not needed,... best sample is the question: do you know at all times where all software that is running saves the data? (not only hibernation, virtual memory... also a text editor can save the text file you are editing in a place you can not know)... just as an example, open (latest versions) Notepad++ write some text but do not save it, close NotePadd++ and reboot if you are not conviced, then re open Notepad++ and the not saved text is there, so t has saved somewhere we do not know where.

So to secure data... and be on the safe line... never ever use that data on systems where you can not have under your own control the 100% system encription.

Not to say, beware what apps are installed (key loggers, etc).

Paranoid: For windows do not trust Bitlocker, keys are sent to M$ servers and NSA, etc.,... and has been discavered a Big Back Door.

My personal best choices are: VeraCrypt (Win+Lin) and DiskCryptor (Win only) and LUKs+LVM+LUKs (Lin only).

Yes, i do not trust one LUKs, it is not enoug secure... must chain at least two of them, or three... same for VeraCrypt (use a cascade of two or three algorithms).

Paranoid point of view: I use on Linux a sector to sector loop mount on free space of a Ext4 (i mantain secret start and length and i must type on each boot) over a 5 chain LUKs without headers (very important not to have headers), i boot with Grub2 on an encrypted partition (on LUKS) with a fake grug.cfg (it will boot a dummy linux).

So my paranoid boot: Power On, type encription for /boot, Grub menu appears, i press c to go to console mode, then i type commands to access a Ext4 over a LUKs over LVM over LUKs over a Sector to sector on a Ext4 that is over a LUKs over LVM over LUKs,... and so on, then i can type command to load kernel and initramfs... then boot, i had configured that initramfs to show me a pre-sh console propmt, so i retype all commands and passwords that let me access the rootfs, then i press exit and boot continues with rootfs mounted.... Very ugly each time a kernel update comes... i must do a lot prior to boot... but, hey, we are talking about 'hiding and securing a full Linux'... anything less complex is not secure enough.

Of course... i use a much more complex than that... i also use ZFS and RAID0, etc... on the chains, etc... but that would be another story... not to mention to use between 250 and 750 files of 1MiB size on a list of ten thousand or more, etc... to secure the weak part (just because passphrases of up to 64 bytes are so weak!).

That is the paranoid point of view... make things enough hard to even find there is a Linux there, that any human or machine desist (brute force attack will not work since there is notenough energy on the whole universe to test 1% of the possible combinations) just for a 8GiB USB Stick... imagine for a 1000GiB HDD!

Basic concepts:

- More than 100 pass to wipe data with special tools (patterns) if you want to secure delete info and still use the medium.
- Meld (with heat) the medium if you want to destroy it, format is not enough, wipe neither is enought, etc.
- For sensitive data, put a lot of layers to make acces very hard, use multiple encryption layers, use different pass, algorithms, etc on each one.
- Hide your OS inside free space of a partition, but be sure that section will not be able to be detected unless that partition can be mounted (never use: Physical, then Ext4, then sector X to Y... that Ext4 will reveal where you have encrypted dat.
- Use the same encryption algorithms on the two near layers, where that Ext4 is and for the sector to sector part, else testing algorithms can reveal the start point.
- Never ever use more than 1% of the whole disk for sensitive data, and put on the rest a near similar difficoult layers with a lot of dummies.

Main idea: Search a Coin on a Galaxy, not on a Planet, not on a city, not on a farm, etc... hide your Coin on a Galaxy sized equivalent... and put layers that make a big effort in energy and time to access it, just to find the Coin is not there... if done well no one will get your data.

Important: Any storage medium can have data not only on Sectors, also on the firmwares, etc... there are some called 'Driver less'... when you connect them they auto-install the needed drivers automatically... think that drivers can had been compromised... so do not connect it to your main computer, etc... use a dummy one without internet, etc... better if it is a Live Linux with no other storage connected, etc.

Etc, etc. i do not want to get people bored!

Comment: "forensic experts ... last 83 states," how long ago was that? Notepad++  (cached files)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617349/notepad-cached-files-location]. You are ignoring that affected devices might be comprised in other ways. E.g. [USB Hacksaw](https://www.hak5.org/usb-hacksaw) uses more than just the part. Do you regularly use your "dummy" Linux? Otherwise your plausible deniability could be compromised. How much of a performance impact does your setup have? You went somewhat of the rails. Obscurity is not Security.